# Three monitor setup: Two are duplicate after reboot! How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, thinkpad

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad which has two video cards: an integrated Intel one and an NVIDIA one. It is connected to two HP monitors through a USB-C docking station. So in total I have three monitors, set to extend mode, and I have not had issues until now.

Today I rebooted my computer and now the two connected monitors are treated as one! It looks like this:

[Image X][Image X][Image Y]

where Image X appears on both external monitors and Image Y appears on the laptop screen. I have tried a handful of things:

- updated the driver on both graphics cards
- reboot with neither monitor connected, then re-connected both monitors
- reboot while everything stays connected
- toggle between "Duplicate" and "Extend" a few times (in "Change Display Settings")
- toggle the same but using Windows Key + P a few times
- disconnecting one monitor, let it settle into [Image X][Image Y] then reconnect third monitor

I can't find anything that works! I did not update any drivers or anything (before the problem started), unless something updated itself in the background. What's going on here?

EDIT: see the image - this used to show 3 but now it shows 2. All three are turned on and displaying an image. It's just not XYZ but XXY instead:
[display settings screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s914m.png)

Comment: I've run into similar issues with multiple monitors on Windows machines.  Not sure if any of these suggestions will work in your situation, but if they do, we can post a definitive answer.  1) Try disabling monitors 2 and 3 in display settings while still connected, so only your laptop screen is used > Multiple Monitors: "Show only on 1", then try adding the others again through "Extend..."  < Toggling directly between Extend and Duplicate has always caused me problems.  2) Try configuring the monitors directly through the Intel and nVidia driver panels instead of the Windows Display Settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! My problem turned out to be with the docking station I used

Answer (score 1):

So TLDR: removing the charger from the [USB docking station](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083JMCRPT) fixed it.

After much experimentation, I believe my **docking station** was the culprit. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083JMCRPT) is the one I'm using.

It has lots of varied inputs, and one USB-C output. It connects to my laptop via USB-C, and all of my devices connect to it through the inputs. Among the inputs is one USB-C input, which I can connect my computer charger to. This is cool because then the docking station is charging my laptop while also connecting all of my devices, with only one cable running to the laptop (the USB-C). But recently I used a MacBook USB-C charger, had no issues... but after that reboot is when the issue started. Switching back to my Lenovo charger **did not fix the problem**, but removing the charger altogether did.